# set user and password for `psql`

Tags: psql

What is the correct way to run `.sql` script using `psql`?

When I do like this

```
psql D:\scripts\script.sql
```

It requires password. I pass my db password `pass` but it shows error

`password authentication failed for user PC_ADMIN`

(i.e. my windows user). But my db user has the name `postgres`.

How to set in command `psql D:\scripts\script.sql\` user and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
psql -U username -d myDataBase -a -f script.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to send the user flag to the script,

```
psql D:\scripts\script.sql -U whateveruser
```

OR

```
psql D:\scripts\script.sql --username=whateveruser
```

otherwise it will assume that the user is the current OS account.